# Filter Stored Procedure Results using Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have this code that get date from server using SP with EF

```
  List<sp_PlacementSearchResult_Result> listResults = new List<sp_PlacementSearchResult_Result>();
  var query = Context.sp_PlacementSearchResult(request.HasamaFormId, request.DepartmentId, request.InstitutionNum, request.IsSigned).AsQueryable();
```

This is working, now i'd like to add some filter to the result like this:

```
 if (role.PermissionId.Equals((int)Permission.Institution))
        {
            query = query.Where(form => PropRole.InstitutionNum.Contains((int)form.OrganizationOrInstitutionNum));
        }
```

at the end of the function when i try to do

```
 listResults = query.ToList();
```

I get error, "Nullable object must have a value."
  The ToList() fail only if it's get into the if statement.

P.S: 
At first i have done this query with EF without SP like this:

```
  var query = Context.APP_AuthorityHasamaForm.AsQueryable();
```

And in that way i have no problem doing the ToList() even if it get into the if statement

Thanx

Edit: this is all the function:

```
  IEnumerable<sp_PlacementSearchResult_Result> IAuthorityHasamaFormRepository.GetByRequestFromSP(PlacementRequest request, APP_Role role, PropertiesRole PropRole)
    {
        List<sp_PlacementSearchResult_Result> listResults = new List<sp_PlacementSearchResult_Result>();

        request.HasamaFormId = (request.HasamaFormId > 0) ? request.HasamaFormId : null;
        request.InstitutionNum = (request.InstitutionNum > 0) ? request.InstitutionNum : null;

        if (request.StartDate.HasValue)
        {
            request.StartDate = new DateTime(request.StartDate.Value.Year, request.StartDate.Value.Month, request.StartDate.Value.Day, 00, 00, 00);

        }

        if (request.EndDate.HasValue)
        {
            request.EndDate = new DateTime(request.EndDate.Value.Year, request.EndDate.Value.Month, request.EndDate.Value.Day, 00, 00, 00);

        }

        var query = Context.sp_PlacementSearchResult(request.HasamaFormId, request.DepartmentId, request.InstitutionNum, request.IsSigned, request.IdentityIdSign,
            request.StartDate, request.EndDate, request.AuthorityNum, request.CertificateNum, null).AsQueryable();

        if (role.PermissionId.Equals((int)Permission.Department))
        {
            query = query.Where(form => PropRole.DepartmentId.Contains(form.DepartmentId));
        }

        if (role.PermissionId.Equals((int)Permission.Institution))
        {
            query = query.Where(form => PropRole.InstitutionNum.Contains((int)form.OrganizationOrInstitutionNum));
        }

        try
        {
            listResults = query.ToList();
            return listResults;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }

         listResults = query.ToList();

        return listResults;
    }
```

Comment: What means "at the end of the function". Can you show us your code around the `if`` block, or your whole function.

Comment: I add the all function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider possible null values of `form.OrganizationOrInstitutionNum`

```
 if (role.PermissionId.Equals((int)Permission.Institution))
        {
            query = query.Where(form => form.OrganizationOrInstitutionNum != null && PropRole.InstitutionNum.Contains(form.OrganizationOrInstitutionNum.Value));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify which is a nullable type on your mode. Then there are some possibilities. For sample, the statment bellow:

```
 query = query.Where(form => PropRole.InstitutionNum.Contains((int)form.OrganizationOrInstitutionNum));
```

if `form.OrganizationOrInstitutionNum` is null, the cast to `int` will fail. Try this:

```
query = query.Where(form => form.OrganizationOrInstitutionNum.HasValue && PropRole.InstitutionNum.Contains((int)form.OrganizationOrInstitutionNum.Value));
```

Maybe you can be save to cast it.